# How to sum only values in one column that have a unique value in another column?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Good afternoon, this is my first post on SU but have used the resource often to help me solve various queries.

I haven't had any luck in finding an answer to the following:

In excel for mac v15 I have a large table with a column I want to sum. However the column has duplicate values in it (for a reason that I can't change). Column A has unique IDs for each row that has distinct data. The ID is repeated for those rows that are duplicates. An example is as follows:

```
A --------- B ------------ C  
ID --- COLOUR --- VALUE  
1 ----- Orange -------- 4  
2 ------Brown --------- 3  
2 ----- Red ------------ 3  
2 ----- Green --------- 3  
3 ----- Blue ----------- 8  
4 ----- Green --------- 2  
4 ----- Brown --------- 2  
5 ----- Purple --------- 6  
5 ----- Brown --------- 6  
5 ----- Red ------------ 6  
6 ----- Blue ----------- 2
```

So I am trying to create a formula which will sum Column C, but disregard the rows where Column A has a repeated ID number - the answer in the example would be (4+3+8+2+6+2) = 25

Any help on this would be much appreciated, and if you need any more information then let me know! Thank you.

EDIT: Thank you everyone so far for your help, all suggestions seem to work well. To make things slightly more complicated:

[Table 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NCHCR.png)
I now need to be able to sum Column D if Column E says "Ordered" and then Column B says "Small" while still ignoring the duplicates like before. So in this example the answer would be (4+8+6)=18.

The data for the table comes from a data dump and so there will not always be the same number of rows of data, and there will not always be each text option present in the table. I should have mentioned this first off but thought I might be able to sort the latter part once I knew how to do the first bit!

Thanks again for any help offered! Much appreciated.

Comment: You will need a helper column.

Answer (score 2):

We can use a Helper column <strike>to avoid array formulas</strike>.  In **D1** enter ***1***, in **D2** enter:

```
=IF(COUNTIF($A$1:A1,A2)>0,0,1)
```

and copy down.  This "marks" the values to be added.  Then in another cell:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(C:C*D:D)
```

[image]

Comment: SUMPRODUCT is an Array type formula. :)

Comment: @ScottCraner  you are correct.... *(in some sense)*

Comment: You could change the first formula to `=IF(COUNTIF($A$1:A1,A2)>0,0,A2)` then Simply sum: `SUM(D:D)`

Comment: Thank you Gary and Scott for your help so far - very useful. I've edited the original question and was wondering if you guys might be able to take a look to see if you can help further? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need for an extra column, just use 
a formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(N(A1:A11<>A2:A12),C2:C12)
```

Note, it's not an array formula, just a plain one.

[image]

**Edit**:

You can combine the conditions as follows:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(N(A2:A25<>A1:A24)*(E1:E24="Ordered")*(B1:B24="Small"),D1:D24)
```

still a single plain formula.

[image]

**Edit2**:

Using a hint from [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1172982/351283)
to get the last row with the number in column `A`,
you can use this monster function

```
=SUMPRODUCT(N(OFFSET($A$1,,,MATCH(99^99,$A:$A,1))<>OFFSET($A$2,,,MATCH(99^99,$A:$A,1)))*(OFFSET($E$1,,,MATCH(99^99,$A:$A,1))="Ordered")*(OFFSET($B$1,,,MATCH(99^99,$A:$A,1))="Small"),OFFSET($D$1,,,MATCH(99^99,$A:$A,1)))
```

which supposed to work with arbitrary number of rows.

[image]

Comment: Hi g.kov. Thank you for your simple formula which gives the option of not having to use a helper column. As mentioned above I don't suppose you would be able to take a look at the edited question to see if you can help me with the next part? Thank you very much.

Comment: @sipound: updated.