# How to add only values in one column that have a unique value and still be able to retain the sum even after sorting?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016, sorting

[Original Problem](https://superuser.com/questions/1216195/how-to-sum-only-values-in-one-column-that-have-a-unique-value-in-another-column)

just an addition to this problem. the sum of the column changes when sorting out a different column. is there a way that we retain the sum even after sorting?

[RTN sorted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tuvp8.png)

Example:
I want to sum all values in the nr column depending on the unique value of the RTN column.
However, if i sort them based on the Gaps column, the sum of nr and nt changes and produces the wrong answer.

[Gaps sorted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z07Q4.png)

Comment: Better Select all NR, RTN and Gaps then Sort on Gaps , will keep the order

Comment: doing this will only sort those specific columns. we want the other columns to go with as well and still retain the sum

Comment: ,, better share data on Cloud or post upload on drop box.